# Combining multiple selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a solution to make this code cleaner:

```
$(document).keypress(function(ev){
         if($("#dialog").is(':visible') === false && $("#alertDialog").is(':visible') === false){
            if(ev.keyCode=='13' && !$('#resetBtn').is(':focus') && !$('.edit-new').is(':focus') && !$('.edit-trash').is(':focus')){
                return validateForm('valueTable');
            } 
            if(ev.keyCode=='27'){
                $('#resetBtn').click();
            }
         }
     });
```

As you can see, I'm checking to see if three seperate inputs are not in foucs before exectuing my event. Is there a way to target #resetBtn, .edit-new, .edit-trash into one, nicely packed selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like this `$('#resetBtn, .edit-new, .edit-trash')` :)

Comment: I swear I tried this solution before but it didn't work before. But this works perfectly!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to tell whether any of these sub-selectors contain matches that are, or are not, focused.

Answer (score 3):

Would this do what you want?

`$('#resetBtn:focus, .edit-new:focus, .edit-trash:focus').length === 0`

You could use a similar statement for your visibility checks too.

Comment: I like this solution a lot, but I decided to go with .is(':focus), as I think it's a bit more semantic. However, this notation would be great if I do anything else to the selections other than just see if they're there! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use single selectors and simply check the length of their returned elements. No reason to explicitly check for equality with `false` when we can check the length property instead:

```
// Handle the keypress event on the document object
$(document).on("keypress", function (event) {
    // Proceed if no visible dialogs
    if (!$("#dialog:visible, #alertDialog:visible").length) {
        // Checking which key was pressed
        switch (event.which) {
            case 13:
                // If no focus is on #resetBtn, .edit-new, or .edit-trash
                if (!$("#resetBtn:focus, .edit-new:focus, .edit-trash:focus").length) {
                    return validateForm("valueTable");
                }
                break;
            case 27:
                // Trigger the click event on #resetBtn
                $("#resetBtn").trigger("click");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is great at condensing my code! However, what's the difference between using .on vs .keypress?

Comment: `$.fn.keypress` internally calls `$.on`. By using `$.on` directly you get a negligible performance boost, plus it's far easier to implement event-delegation using `$.on` than it is using `$.fn.keypress`.